# discord.py bot crashes after a few hours

Tags: python, discord.py, crash

it crashes with a very long error message about the token but the token isnt the problem as it worked for the past couple of hours, when it crashes i go to the console and type kill 1, it work fine after that but after a few hours it does it again. this is a bot that is written on replit.

i was wondering if there was a way to make it stay online without crashing (i am using uptimerobot already)

here is the code

```
#imports#######################################################################################################################imports#
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.utils import get
from replit import db
import random
from itertools import cycle
import keep_alive
import os

#starting#####################################################################################################################starting#

status = cycle(['.help', '..help'])
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command('help')

async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    client.loop.create_task(change_status())
    print("CYKLERBOT is ready, you can now leave the tab")

#member-update###########################################################################################################member-update#

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} has joined a server.')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} has left a server')

#economy###################################################################################################################economy#
    
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx, *, user):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    value = db["m" + user]
    await ctx.send(f'{user}, your balance is ${value}')
    print(value)
    print(user)

@client.command(aliases=['create'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def createwallet(ctx, *, user):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    db["m" + user] = 0
    await ctx.send(f'{user}s wallet has been created')

@client.command(aliases=['add'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def addmoney(ctx, user, *, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    value = db["m" + user]
    db["m" + user] = value + amount
    await ctx.send(f'{amount} has been added to {user}s wallet')

@client.command(aliases=['set'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def setmoney(ctx, user, *, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    db["m" + user] = amount
    await ctx.send(f'{user}s wallet had been set to {amount}')

@client.command(aliases=['remove'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def removemoney(ctx, user, *, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    value = db["m" + user]
    db[user + 'm'] = value - amount
    await ctx.send(f'{amount} has been removed from {user}s wallet')

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def delete(ctx, *, user):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    del db[user]
    await ctx.send(f'{user}s account has been deleted')

@client.command(aliases=['wkeys'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def walletkeys(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    matches = db.prefix("m")
    await ctx.send(f'{matches}')

#inventory###################################################################################################################inventory#

@client.command(aliases=['createi'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def createinventory(ctx, *, user):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    db['i' + user] = []
    await ctx.send(f'{user}s inventory has been created')

@client.command(aliases=['inv'])
async def inventory(ctx, *, user):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    value = db['i' + user]
    await ctx.send(f'{user}s inventory contains {value}')

@client.command(aliases=['give'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def giveitem(ctx, user, *, item):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    value = db['i' + user]
    value.append(item)
    await ctx.send(f'{item}, has been added to {user}s inventory')

@client.command(aliases=['take'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def takeitem(ctx, user, *, item):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    value = db['i' + user]
    value.remove(item)
    await ctx.send(f'{item}, has been removed from {user}s inventory')

@client.command(aliases=['ikeys'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def inventorykeys(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    matches = db.prefix("i")
    await ctx.send(f'{matches}')
#warnings###################################################################################################################warnings#

@client.command(aliases=['createww'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def createwarnwallet(ctx, *, user):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    db['ww' + user] = []
    await ctx.send(f'{user}s warn wallet has been created')

@client.command()
async def warnings(ctx, *, user):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    value = db['ww' + user]
    await ctx.send(f'{user}s warn wallet contains {value}')

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def warn(ctx, user, *, item):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    value = db['ww' + user]
    value.append(item)
    await ctx.send(f'{user} has been warned with {item}')

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def dewarn(ctx, user, *, item):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    value = db['ww' + user]
    value.remove(item)
    await ctx.send(f'{user}s warning ({item}) has been removed')

@client.command(aliases=['warncount'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def warningcount(ctx, *, user):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    value = db['ww' + user]
    
    await ctx.send(f'{user} has {len(value)} warnings')

@client.command(aliases=['wwkeys'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def warningkeys(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    matches = db.prefix("ww")
    await ctx.send(f'{matches}')

#polls###########################################################################################################################polls#

@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f"{message}",
                        description=f"asked by @{ctx.message.author}",
                        colour=random.choice(rcolor))
    msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=emb)
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')


@client.command()
async def mpoll(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title=f"{message}",
                        description=f"asked by @{ctx.message.author}",
                        colour=random.choice(rcolor))
    msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=emb)
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')



#fun###############################################################################################################################fun#

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')

@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    responces = [
        'It is certain', 'It is decidedly so', 'Without a doubt',
        'Yes definitely', 'You may rely on it', 'As I see it, yes',
        'Most likely', 'Outlook good', 'Yes', 'Signs point to yes',
        'Reply hazy, try again', 'Ask again later', 'Better not tell you now',
        'Cannot predict now', 'Concentrate and ask again', 'Dont count on it',
        'My reply is no', 'My sources say no', 'Outlook not so good',
        'Very doubtful'
    ]
    await ctx.send(f'Question: {question}\nAnswer: {random.choice(responces)}')

@client.command()
async def coinflip(ctx):
    responces2 = [
        'heads',
        'tails',
    ]
    await ctx.send(random.choice(responces2))

@client.command()
async def roll(ctx, amount1: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await ctx.send(f'you rolled a {random.randrange(1, amount1 + 1)}')

#admin###########################################################################################################################admin#

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def undo(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=2)

@purge.error
async def purge_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('ERROR MSG: ||please specify an amount of messages to delete||')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
      await ctx.send("ERROR MSG: ||You do not have the permission to use that command!||")

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await user.remove_roles("manager")
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Kicked {member.mention} Reason: {reason}')

@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('ERROR MSG: ||please specify the person to kick followed by the reason||')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("ERROR MSG: ||You do not have the permission to use that command!||")

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await user.remove_roles("manager")
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'Banned {member.mention} Reason: {reason}')

@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('ERROR MSG: ||please specify the person to ban followed by the reason||')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("ERROR MSG: ||You do not have the permission to use that command!||")

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name,
                                               member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
            return

@unban.error
async def unban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('ERROR MSG: ||please specify the person to unban followed by the tag||')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send("ERROR MSG: ||You do not have the permission to use that command!||")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def role(ctx, user : discord.Member, *, role : discord.Role):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    if role in user.roles:
        await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} already had that role, {role}')
    else:
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f'{role} has been added to {user.mention}')

@role.error
async def role_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('ERROR MSG: ||please specify the @ that you would like to role followed by the role that you would like to give||')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send("ERROR MSG: ||You do not have the permission to use that command!||")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def derole(ctx, user : discord.Member, *, role : discord.Role):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    if role in user.roles:
        await user.remove_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f'{role} has been removed from {user.mention}')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} does not have this role{role}')

@derole.error
async def derole_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('ERROR MSG: ||please specify the @ that you would like to derole followed by the role that you would like to remove||')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send("ERROR MSG: ||You do not have the permission to use that command!||")
        
#help command#############################################################################################################help command#

rcolor = [
    discord.Colour.purple(),
    discord.Colour.orange(),
    discord.Colour.green(),
    discord.Colour.blue(),
    discord.Colour.red(),
    discord.Colour.teal(),
    discord.Colour.dark_teal(),
    discord.Colour.dark_green(),
    discord.Colour.dark_blue(),
    discord.Colour.dark_purple(),
    discord.Colour.magenta(),
    discord.Colour.dark_magenta(),
    discord.Colour.gold(),
    discord.Colour.dark_gold(),
    discord.Colour.dark_orange(),
    discord.Colour.dark_red(),
    discord.Colour.lighter_gray(),
    discord.Colour.dark_gray(),
    discord.Colour.light_gray(),
    discord.Colour.darker_gray(),
    discord.Colour.blurple(),
    discord.Colour.greyple()
]

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    embed = discord.Embed(colour=random.choice(rcolor))

    embed.add_field(name='.ping',
                    value='Returns Pong! + the response time',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.8ball [insert question here]',
                    value='returns a random yes/no type answer',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.coinflip',
                    value='Returns heads or tails',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(
        name='.roll [insert value here]',
        value='Returns a random value from 1 to the specified number',
        inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.ping',
                    value='Returns Pong! + the response time',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.poll, [insert question here]',
                    value='outputs an embed pole with automatic reactions',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(
        name='.mpoll, [inset question here]',
        value='outputs an embed pole with 7 automatic reactions',
        inline=False)
    
    embed.add_field(name='.balance [insert wallet user here]',
                    value='Returns the amount of money the wallet user has',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.inventory [insert inventory user here]',
                    value='Returns all items that the user has',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='MOD ONLY!!! .modhelp',
                    value='hows .help with moderator commands',
                    inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def modhelp(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    embed = discord.Embed(colour=random.choice(rcolor))

    embed.add_field(name='.ban [insert @ here], [insert reason here]',
                    value='bans specified member/bot for the specified reason',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.unban [insert name here + tag]',
                    value='unbans specified member/bot',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.purge [insert value here]',
                    value='removes the specified amount of messages (-1)',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.undo',
                    value='removes the previous message',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.kick [insert @ here], [insert reason here]',
                    value='kicks specified member/bot for the specified reason',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.role [insert @ here], [insert role here]',
                    value='adds the specified role to the specified user',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.derole [insert @ here], [insert role here]',
                    value='removes the specified role from the specified user',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.delete [insert user here]',
                    value='deletes the users wallet/inventory',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.modhelpwarnings',
                    value='shows all moderator warning commands',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.modhelpwallet',
                    value='shows all moderator warning commands',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.modhelpinventory',
                    value='shows all moderator warning commands',
                    inline=False)
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def modhelpwarnings(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    embed = discord.Embed(colour=random.choice(rcolor))

    embed.add_field(name='.createwarnwallet [insert warning user here]',
                    value='creates a warning wallet for the specified user',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.warnings [insert warning user here]',
                    value='gives all the warnings of the specified user',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.warn [insert warning user here] [insert violation here]',
                    value='adds the warning to the specified users wallet',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.dewarn [insert warning user here] [insert violation here',
                    value='removes the specified warning from the specified user',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.warncount [insert warning user here]',
                    value='give the amount of warnings the specified user has',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.warningkeys',
                    value='gives all users that have a warning account',
                    inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def modhelpwallet(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    embed = discord.Embed(colour=random.choice(rcolor))

    embed.add_field(name='.create [insert wallet user here]',
                    value='creates a wallet for the specified user',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.set [insert wallet user here], [insert amount here]',
                    value='sets the user wallet to given amount',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.add [insert wallet user here], [insert amount here]',
                    value='adds the amount to the users wallet',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.remove [insert wallet user here], [insert amount here]',
                    value='removes the amount from ths users wallet',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.wkeys',
                    value='shows all users which have a wallet',
                    inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def modhelpinventory(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

    embed = discord.Embed(colour=random.choice(rcolor))

    embed.add_field(name='.createi [insert inventory user here]',
                    value='creates an inventory for the specified user',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.give [insert inventory user here]',
                    value='gives an item to the specified user',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.take [insert inventory user here]',
                    value='removes an item from the specified user',
                    inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='.ikeys',
                    value='shows all users which have an inventory',
                    inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

#end###############################################################################################################################end#

keep_alive.keep_alive()
client.run("TOKEN")
```

every time it crashes i type kill 1 in the console and it works. but it crashes again after a few hours.

i just hope that i can get it working 24/7 because the people on my server are getting annoyed

Comment: Replit uses a shared IP address, so if someone gets rate limited from Discord, everyone else that is also using it to host their bots will also get rate limited. Even if you use `kill 1`, you will get rate limited again after some time. If you want your bot to be online 24/7, you should get a VPS.

Comment: @catgal if i have a vps how can i set it up to support my replit bot